# Continuity of Laplace Transform using MVT

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, laplace-transform

How can we show that :
$$
F(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-sx}\;\text{d}x
$$
Is continuous in $(r,\infty)$? I was thinking of using Mean Value Theorem but I got stuck in the process.

Comment: Do you know Lebesgue Dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: Unfortunately this theorem is way too ahead of me :( @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: Are you dealing with Lebesgue or Riemann integral?

Comment: However, I am aware and proved the weaker version of it @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net The Riemann Integral